# how to layer svg polygons

Tags: svg, layer

i'd like to "layer" polygons, i mean to put the brighter one under the darker one, here's code

```html
 <svg class="background-shape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polygon points="0 100,100 100,0 0,0 "/>
    <polygon points="0 100 54 46 5 0 0 0 0 100"/>
   </svg>
```

and that's how it looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KGRC.jpg

Comment: in your code you don't have a brighter one and a darker one.  However if you need to put one shape over another put the bottom shape first and the top one second. Also add a fill attribute to your polygones